# Tooltips for panel

Tags: java, swing, awt

For text boxes we can add tooltips by ui. I am struggling with adding tooltips for panels.How to add tooltips for java.awt.Panel? Should I use a mouse event? Can anyone suggest a proper method.

Comment: [`JComponent#setToolTipText`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/JComponent.html#setToolTipText-java.lang.String-) - Tool tip support is built into the base component

Answer (score 1):

> .How to add tooltips for java.awt.Panel?

Tooltips are for Swing components.

Use a `JPanel` and the `setToolTipText(...)` method.

Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [How to Use Tool Tips](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/tooltip.html) for more information

Comment: But I have used java.awt.panel? I cannot use setToolTipText() method for it.

Comment: `But I have used java.awt.panel?` - well change your code. There is no reason to use AWT. If you want to use a tooltip then you need to use Swing

Comment: This is my panel private java.awt.Panel panelNumFeild; How can I use JPanel again for it. I am new to java. So I am confusing.

Comment: You import `javax.swing.*` to access all the Swing compnents. Then you can use "JPanel". `I am new to java. ` Read the tutorial The tutorial has working examples of how to use all Swing components. You learn by reading and playing with working examples.

Comment: In your last question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50115067/jbutton-needs-two-clicks-to-respond you were using JButton, which is a Swing component. Using a JPanel is no different than using JButton. Both are Swing components. I don't understand what you find confusing.

Answer (score 0):

To use a JPanel as the guys in the comments said, just use this:

```
        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        panel.setToolTipText("This is tooltip text");
```

if you are still struggling with swing and awt components, check your imports at the beginning of the class:

```
import javax.swing.JPanel;
```

Hope this helps for now :)